# Can't change the colours of divs in component, React Native

Tags: css, react-native, colors, components, react-props

I'm in the middle of building this frontend mentor project:

**Time tracking dashboard**

[image: 1]

I'm building this using React Native, everything is going well, the only thing is **I don't know how to** change these colours:

[image: 2]

If I try to change it in the CSS it'll just change them all to one same colour because, here's my code:

In the activity.jsx:

```
function ActivityCard(props) {
  return (
    <div className="cards">
      <div class="activityImage">
        <img src={props.image} alt="Activity Glimpse" />
      </div>

      <div className="activityDetail">
        <p class="activityText">{props.activity}</p>
        <img class="morebtn" src={props.more} alt="More" />

        <div class="clear"></div>

        <h1>{props.duration}</h1>
        <p>{props.pastDuration}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In the app.jsx:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="container">{Schedule.map(createActivity)}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is the top part which colour needs to be change:

```
<div class="activityImage">
    <img src={props.image} alt="Activity Glimpse" />
</div>
```

Hope you can help. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Are you making those 6 cards one by one? or using by map?

Comment: I'm making them by map

Comment: then pass those color via map

Comment: I maped the image, the image is in a div. I want to change the div to different colours

Comment: Can anyone help me with this?